# how do i download node.js 15.10.0 to mac

Tags: node.js, macos, command-line-interface

when ever I put `touch ~/.bash_profile` in the terminal I get `-bash: touch: command not found`

I had it installed before but if I do `npm -v`, `node -v`, or `nvm -v` it always comes back as `-bash: touch: command not found`

Is there a way i can install node 15.10.0?

Comment: `touch: command not found` so the *touch* command is either not there, not in path or not executable

Comment: Your $PATH might be broken. Check your bashrc and profile.

Comment: so what would i use if 'touch ~/.bash_profile' didn't work

Comment: Why do you need touch? You can install and use node version manager for installing node version you want. I've added an answer about it

Comment: Note: Your specific error has nothing to do with Node. Also, MacOS has switched to ZSH as the **default** shell, so you need to edit `~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to install Node.js on a Mac. One of the most popular ways is via Node Version Manager: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm. The README shows you how to setup and use `nvm` for installing any Node.js version.

Comment: am i supposed to redownload curl or homebrew

Comment: @Tim As written in the README `homebrew` installations of `nvm` are not supported. Your mac should come with `curl` (as well as `touch`)

Comment: i got '-bash: curl: No such file or directory' for 'curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash'

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac...

```
$ ls /usr/bin | grep touch
touch
```

If yours doesn't have it, then your system got messed up somehow.

If it is there, then you have removed `/usr/bin` from your `$PATH` variable, and you should add it back

Answer (score 0):

You can download the nodejs from the official website of nodejs https://nodejs.org/en/download/ and after that open the download folder and check all the options:
By the way, you can watch my video in the Hindi language:
https://youtu.be/M24FHfCBlJc